# Recommended Open source Tool for Statistics

Tags: open-source, statistics

I'm looking for a statistical tool (similar tool as SPSS, [Minitab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minitab) and SAS) that is open source. Any recommendation?

In this context, I prefer drop and click. Not coding as R please.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Specifically: instead just writing "similar to X", explicitly name your requirements. It might well be people not familiar with SPSS, minitab *and* SAS still now exactly the tool you're after :)

Comment: There are so many open source tools for statistics, we can't help you if you don't give more details. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: There is PSPP (https://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/) which is similar to SPSS. I never used it, though.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Orange](http://orange.biolab.si/) for explaining simple stats to my sales team.

It is a simple GUI drag and drop tool, which helps you do tasks ranging from simple statistics to complex machine learning.

I prefer it mainly due to the polished GUI, which makes the statistical analyses easy and interesting for non-stats folks.

It also comes in the form of a Python library, just in case you like the tool and want to use it for complex analytics too.

Answer (score 1):

Like @fxm said, there is also PSPP which is another powerful application that would meet your needs.

## [PSPP](http://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/) (Open Source)

> PSPP is a free software application for analysis of sampled data. It
>   has a graphical user interface and conventional command line
>   interface. It is written in C, uses GNU Scientific Library for its
>   mathematical routines, and plotutils for generating graphs. It is
>   intended as a free replacement of the proprietary program, SPSS.
>
> [image: PSPP]

Comment: Can you combine all your answers into a single one? Would be much better to look at.

Comment: No, you should *never* combine multiple pieces of software in just one answer. As stated on meta, "**[one recommendation per answer](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-to-do-when-an-answer-contains-several-suggestions/388#388)**"

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few answers to this questions but I'll limit my response to three,

First I would check out RKWard. It uses the backend of R but has a very nice and easy to use interface. It is available for Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X.

## [RKWard](https://rkward.kde.org/) (Open Source)

> RKWard is an easy to use and easily extensible IDE/GUI for R. It aims
> to combine the power of the R-language with the ease of use of
> commercial statistics tools.
>
> RKWard's features include:
>
> - Spreadsheet-like data editor
> - Syntax highlighting, code folding and code completion
> - Data import (e.g. SPSS, Stata and CSV)
> - Plot preview and browsable history
> - R package management
> - Workspace browser
> - GUI dialogs for all kinds of statistics and plots
>
> Its features can be extended by plugins, and it's all free software.
>
> [image: RKWard]

Answer (score 0):

Last but not least, I would check out SOFA, short for Statistics Open For All. This application's main focus is for ease of use. It also runs on Windows, Linux, and OS X.

## [SOFA](http://www.sofastatistics.com/home.php) (Open Source)

> SOFA Statistics is an open-source statistical package, with an
>   emphasis on ease of use, learn as you go, and beautiful output. The
>   name stands for Statistics Open For All. It has a graphical user
>   interface and can connect directly to MySQL, SQLite, MS Access, and MS
>   SQL Server. Data can also be imported from CSV or MS Excel files. The
>   main statistical tests available are Independent and Paired t-tests,
>   Wilcoxon signed ranks, Mann–Whitney U, Pearsons chi square, Kruskal
>   Wallis H, one-way ANOVA, Spearmans R, and Pearsons R. Nested tables
>   can be produced with row and column percentages, totals, sd, mean,
>   median, and sum.
>
> [image: SOFA Screenshot]